# test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

My question is not about a failing test; all tests pass, until now.
The code example is in Michael Hartl's book (you probably guessed that already).
I look at this test:

```
test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong" do
  @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
  assert_nil current_user
end
```

My question simply is: explain me, please, why is the `remember_digest` wrong here? What can make it wrong?

For your further information, the file is `test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb`, and is starts with this method:

```
  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    remember(@user)
  end
```

`users(:michael)` is defined in the file `test/fixtures/users.yml`

Comment: Maybe I understand now: the ```remember(@user)``` method has already created a ```remember_digest``` and a ```remember_token``` in a cookie. When the ```remember_digest``` is updated with new information, there is no match any more with the ```remember_token```.
Just a guess; I still am quite confused. I am beginner, still have to grasp a lot ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You got it right - this test makes sure that `current_user` is `nil` when the `remember_digest`is wrong, which means that the user is not logged in if the cookie is different from expected.

> Note that we’ve added a second test, which checks that the current
>   user is nil if the user’s remember digest doesn’t correspond correctly
>   to the remember token, thereby testing the authenticated? expression
>   in the nested if statement:
>
> ```
> if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
> ```

[Chapter 9](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/advanced_login)

The `setup` is run before the test:

```
def setup
  @user = users(:michael)
  remember(@user)
end
```

and the `remember` function sets the user's `remember_digest` by setting a `remember_token` in the cookie:

```
# Remembers a user in a persistent session.
def remember(user)
  user.remember
  cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

The test then replaces the user's `remember_digest` with the digest of a random value, thus invalidating the cookie:

```
@user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
```

So `current_user`is `nil`, which means that no user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

```
  def current_user
      if (user_id = session[:user_id]) # i.e., if the user is logged in (has a session w/ user's id)
          @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
      elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id]) 
          user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
          if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
              log_in user
              @current_user = user
          end
      end
  end
```

(from sessions_helper.rb) - specifically, look at the statement:

```
if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
```

Notice, that if `user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])` fails then the instance variable `@current_user` will not be assigned whatsoever. In such a case, the value of `@current_user` will be nil.

To get a better idea, in rails console, try:

```
>> user = User.create(name: "Michael", email: "example@michael.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
>> user.remember_token 
=> nil
>> user.remember
>> user.remember_token
=> "68ObMQCCdjURdwH0QVEL7w"
>> token = user.remember_token
>> user.authenticated?(token)
=> true
>> user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
>> user.authenticated?(token)
=> false
```

To make the last line `=> true`:

```
>> user.remember
>> new_token = user.remember_token
>> user.authenticated?(new_token)
=> true
```

Now looking back at the session_helper_test.rb, since the `remember` method is called in the setup, but not after `@user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))` in the test block, we can expect that `user.authenticated?(user.remember_token)` will fail. As a result, the statement `if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])` will be `false`. So `@current_user` is never given a value, and will therefore be `nil`.